# Small Case for full size graphics card + swappable hdd

Tags: case

I am looking for a small case with the following requirements:

Hardware that should fit in:

- ASRock H77 Pro4/MVP, Sockel 1155, ATX
- Gigabiyte Radeon HD 7950
- 4 HDD + 1 SSD
- be quiet! Pure Power L7 530

Following features of the case:

- got swappable HDDs (SSD is not a must)
- as small as possible
- maybe RGB Support
- 2-3 USB at the front
- Noise reduction
- good airflow

There is no budget limitations so please give me every recommendation you have.

Comment: Do you have any distinct dimensions you need a case to fit into? Any objective measures of "small"?

Comment: @JaredT no, just as small as possible